# Call the same activity with new intent

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, dialog, android-dialog

i'm new in Android and i have problems using Intent. I hope you can help me.

I would like, inside an activity, to open a dialog with a button. When you press the button, it loads again the same acitvity but with some parameters reset.
It's like round 1, and then round 2.

I have an end-dialog that works because it calls another acitivity
The 2nd dialog works fine, i use show inside another class(inside a method of the class partida), but he problem is when i push OK when the popup of next round opens. I don't know what may i put there.
Also i have declared some static and normal variables.

This is my code:

```
        partida partida;
    public String animal, oculta, vidasS, puntosS, rondaS;
    public TextView palabra, vidasrest, puntostot, rondanum;
    ImageView vida;
    Button []btn=new Button[27];
    static int vidas=5;
    static int puntos=0;
    static int ronda=1;

    static AlertDialog.Builder finalpartida, rondanueva;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            partida=new partida();
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_partida);

            finalpartida = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);  
            finalpartida.setTitle("Final de la partida");  
            finalpartida.setMessage("Click OK para finalizar partida");            
            finalpartida.setCancelable(false);  
            finalpartida.setNegativeButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {  
                public void onClick(DialogInterface finalpartida, int id) {  
                    //Creamos el Intent
                    Intent intent = new Intent(PartidaActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                    vidas=5;
                    ronda=1;
                    puntos=0;
                    finish();
                    //Iniciamos la nueva actividad
                    startActivity(intent);
                }  
            });

            animal=partida.animal;
            oculta=partida.inicializa(animal);
            palabra = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.wordtxt);
            palabra.setText(oculta);
            vidasrest = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtvidas);
            vidasS = Integer.toString(vidas);
            vidasrest.setText("Vidas: "+vidasS);
            vida = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imgvidas);
            puntostot = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtPuntos);
            puntosS = Integer.toString(puntos);
            puntostot.setText("Puntos: "+puntosS);
            rondanum = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtronda);
            rondaS = Integer.toString(ronda);
            rondanum.setText("Ronda: "+rondaS);

            rondanueva = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);  
            rondanueva.setTitle("Fin de ronda "+ronda);  
            rondanueva.setMessage("Click OK para siguiente ronda");            
            rondanueva.setCancelable(false);  
            rondanueva.setNegativeButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {  
                public void onClick(DialogInterface rondanueva, int id) {  
                    vidas=5;
                    ronda++;
//THIS DOESN'T WORK
                    Intent intent = new Intent(PartidaActivity.this, RondaActivity.class);
                    finish();
                    startActivity(intent);
                    //NEITHER THIS: ((Activity) rondanueva).setTitle("Fin de ronda "+ronda);


                    animal=partida.animal;//nombre del animal
                    oculta=partida.inicializa(animal);//estructuro palabra vacía
                    palabra.setText(oculta);
                    vidasS = Integer.toString(vidas);
                    vidasrest.setText("Vidas: "+vidasS);
                    vida.setImageResource(R.drawable.vidas5);
                    rondaS = Integer.toString(ronda);
                    rondanum.setText("Ronda: "+rondaS);

                }  
            });

        }
```

ERROR LOG When i use Intent i=getIntent() ; startActivity(i) ; inside the onClick

09-09 17:07:09.294: W/System.err(329): java.lang.NullPointerException: asset
09-09 17:07:09.294: W/System.err(329):  at android.content.res.AssetManager.readAsset(Native Method)
09-09 17:07:09.354: W/System.err(329):  at android.content.res.AssetManager.access$700(AssetManager.java:36)
09-09 17:07:09.354: W/System.err(329):  at android.content.res.AssetManager$AssetInputStream.read(AssetManager.java:572)
09-09 17:07:09.364: W/System.err(329):  at org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatParser.parseFragment(ExpatParser.java:516)
09-09 17:07:09.364: W/System.err(329):  at org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatParser.parseDocument(ExpatParser.java:479)
09-09 17:07:09.364: W/System.err(329):  at org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatReader.parse(ExpatReader.java:318)
09-09 17:07:09.374: W/System.err(329):  at org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatReader.parse(ExpatReader.java:275)
09-09 17:07:09.374: W/System.err(329):  at org.jdom2.input.sax.SAXBuilderEngine.build(SAXBuilderEngine.java:217)
09-09 17:07:09.374: W/System.err(329):  at org.jdom2.input.sax.SAXBuilderEngine.build(SAXBuilderEngine.java:253)
09-09 17:07:09.374: W/System.err(329):  at org.jdom2.input.SAXBuilder.build(SAXBuilder.java:1091)
09-09 17:07:09.374: W/System.err(329):  at org.myproject.ahorcadoanimales.Xml.(Xml.java:25)
09-09 17:07:09.374: W/System.err(329):  at org.myproject.ahorcadoanimales.partida.(partida.java:13)
09-09 17:07:09.394: W/System.err(329):  at org.myproject.ahorcadoanimales.PartidaActivity.onCreate(PartidaActivity.java:36)
09-09 17:07:09.394: W/System.err(329):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
09-09 17:07:09.394: W/System.err(329):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
09-09 17:07:09.394: W/System.err(329):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
09-09 17:07:09.394: W/System.err(329):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
09-09 17:07:09.394: W/System.err(329):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
09-09 17:07:09.394: W/System.err(329):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-09 17:07:09.394: W/System.err(329):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
09-09 17:07:09.394: W/System.err(329):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
09-09 17:07:09.394: W/System.err(329):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-09 17:07:09.424: W/System.err(329):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
09-09 17:07:09.424: W/System.err(329):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
09-09 17:07:09.444: W/System.err(329):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
09-09 17:07:09.444: W/System.err(329):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-09 17:07:09.564: D/AndroidRuntime(329): Shutting down VM
09-09 17:07:09.564: W/dalvikvm(329): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
09-09 17:07:09.604: E/AndroidRuntime(329): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-09 17:07:09.604: E/AndroidRuntime(329): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{org.myproject.ahorcadoanimales/org.myproject.ahorcadoanimales.PartidaActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-09 17:07:09.604: E/AndroidRuntime(329):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
09-09 17:07:09.604: E/AndroidRuntime(329):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
09-09 17:07:09.604: E/AndroidRuntime(329):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
09-09 17:07:09.604: E/AndroidRuntime(329):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
09-09 17:07:09.604: E/AndroidRuntime(329):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-09 17:07:09.604: E/AndroidRuntime(329):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
09-09 17:07:09.604: E/AndroidRuntime(329):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
09-09 17:07:09.604: E/AndroidRuntime(329):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-09 17:07:09.604: E/AndroidRuntime(329):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
09-09 17:07:09.604: E/AndroidRuntime(329):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
09-09 17:07:09.604: E/AndroidRuntime(329):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
09-09 17:07:09.604: E/AndroidRuntime(329):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-09 17:07:09.604: E/AndroidRuntime(329): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-09 17:07:09.604: E/AndroidRuntime(329):  at org.myproject.ahorcadoanimales.partida.inicializa(partida.java:19)
09-09 17:07:09.604: E/AndroidRuntime(329):  at org.myproject.ahorcadoanimales.PartidaActivity.onCreate(PartidaActivity.java:66)
09-09 17:07:09.604: E/AndroidRuntime(329):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
09-09 17:07:09.604: E/AndroidRuntime(329):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
09-09 17:07:09.604: E/AndroidRuntime(329):  ... 11 more

Comment: I'm confused on what you want. It doesn't look like you are trying to start the same `Activity`. You are saying this doesn't work, `Intent intent = new Intent(PartidaActivity.this, RondaActivity.class);`? If so, what doesn't work about it? Please be more specific. Also, I don't think this is very good practice. When you create an `Activity` it has to redraw the layout and resets the variables. You would be better off creating a method to be called when the dialog is dismissed.

Comment: Intent i=getIntent() ; startActivity(i) ;

Comment: The dialog works fine, i use show inside another class(inside a method of the class partida).
The problem is when i push OK in the popup of next round the program crash.

Answer (score 0):

Is the issue that you don't see a dialog box pop up? If not, could you explain what exactly is the problem?

Comment: The dialog works fine, i use show inside another class(inside a method of the class partida).
The problem is when i push OK when the popup of next round opens.

Comment: You say that the app "crashes". Do you see an exception in the log? If you do, you probably should post the exception here, to make it easier to understand what the issue is.

Comment: The show() method is called in the class 'partida'.

Whats wrong about using builders in onCreate method? It works fine for the first dialog.

Comment: (a) Do you see an error message in the log? (b) Using the builders in onCreate() does not cause the issue although in my opinion, using a separate method to handle them would increase readability and modularity of code. My apologies if my question on the builders caused confusion. I have edited my answer/comment.

Answer (score 0):

It's very probable that if the app is crashing every time you try to launch an activity, that activity you try to launch is not properly declared in your AndroidManifest.xml file.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html